# Response is null when trying to fetch CPU utilization metric from Cloudwatch from Lambda using get-metric-statistics

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

i need to create a lambda function which has to fetch CPUUtilization of ec2 from cloudwatch and generate a csv report. When i tried fetching it using following code response is null,

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime

cw = boto3.client(service_name='cloudwatch',region_name = 'ap-south-1')

def lambda_handler(eeeee, context):
    # TODO implement
     response = cw.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace = 'AWS/EC2',
        Period = 600,
        StartTime = '2021-01-27T00:00:00Z',
        EndTime = '2021-01-28T12:00:00Z',
        MetricName = 'CPUUtilization',
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'InstanceId',
                'Value': 'i-0ae327'
            }   
        ] 
    
    )
```

But when i try in AWSCLI am recieving some datapoints,

```
{
  "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
"MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
"Dimensions": [
{
"Name": "InstanceId",
"Value": "i-0ae327"
}
],
"StartTime": "2021-01-27T00:00:00",
"EndTime": "2021-01-28T12:00:00",
"Period": 600,
"Statistics": [
"Average"
]
}
```

What am i missing? Please help out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not returning** anything from your `lambda_handler`.

Assumming that your use of `get_metric_statistics` is correct, you need to add a **return statement**:

```
def lambda_handler(eeeee, context):
     # TODO implement
     response = cw.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace = 'AWS/EC2',
        Period = 600,
        StartTime = '2021-01-27T00:00:00Z',
        EndTime = '2021-01-28T12:00:00Z',
        MetricName = 'CPUUtilization',
        Statistics=['Average'],
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'InstanceId',
                'Value': 'i-0ae327'
            }   
        ]
     )

     return response
```

Comment: Thank you. That was useful. :) (newbie to lambda lunction)